# how to configure JSP URL is spring boot embed tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

am developing application in which am having all my jsp inside the directory /WEB-INF/default/pages/ and below is my application.properties

```
server.port=${server.port}
server.contextPath=/myapplication
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/default/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

When I start my application, I need to hit the below URL to see the login page. But this is not what I want.

```
http://localhost:8081/myapplication/default/pages/login.jsp
```

I want to check hit the below URL to get the login page.

```
http://localhost:8081/signin
```

I made few change for this, but nothing working.

PROBLEM 1:
If I changed to server.contextPath=/ or removed this from application properties, I can able to get the login page at

```
http://localhost:8081/default/pages/login.jsp
```

but the problem here is I cant able to get my session variables when redirect between pages. request.getSession(false) is returning null.

PROBLEM 2:

I cant able to map my login page to the URL also.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login123</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/default/pages/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login123</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Even this is not working.

Security Config:

```
@Configurable
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={EpPermissionValidator.class})
// Modifying or overriding the default spring boot security.
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        logger.info("configure() method started..");
        try {
            web.ignoring()
            // ignoring the "/", "/index.html", "/app/**", "/register",
            // "/favicon.ico"
            .antMatchers("/bus/refresh","/monitoring","/**/*.css","/**/*.js","/**/*.map","/**/*.json", "/login","/signin","/default/pages/login.jsp","/css/**","/ext/**","/js/**","/resources/**","/script/**","/Singapp/**","/style/**","/favicon.ico","/UtilController", "/invalidateSession");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error occured at.."+ e);
        }finally {
            logger.info("configure() method ended..");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("configure() method started..");
        try {
            http
            // starts authorizing configurations
            .authorizeRequests()
            // authenticate all remaining URLS
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            // adding JWT filter
            .addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // enabling the basic authentication
            .httpBasic().and()
            // configuring the session as state less. Which means there is
            // no session in the server
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            // to allow iframe from the same orgin
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
            // disabling the CSRF - Cross Site Request Forgery
            .csrf().disable();          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error occured at.."+ e);
        }finally {
            logger.info("configure() method ended..");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats your security config?

Comment: updated security config @PärNilsson

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966602/spring-boot-mvc-cant-find-jsp?rq=1